# How to create new script , role like wc

Tags: command-line, files, command, wc

I would like to create a new .wc command.

Comment: Do you want to program an script?

Comment: What did you try until now? Any specific problems?

Comment: I want to create new command like wc. and subquery.. FOR example       nc newfile.txt (nc = new command)                                                                                   2 3 6                                                                                                                           nc -c newfile.txt  (character)                                                                                             2                                                                                                                                  nc -w newfile.tx  (word)

Comment: If this is for an exercise, OK, but be aware that the common `wc` command already has command line options to count lines and characters as well as words

Comment: yes , I want to create new script like wc command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the exception of [shell builtins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin), commands are just programs. This means your question reduces to, "How do I write a program?"

(Or, "How do I write a script?" which amounts to the same thing, since a script is just another type of program. The distinction between [scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) and [programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language) is not important to get into here.)

`wc` is a good example, because it is not a shell builtin. It is just another program on the system, typically installed in `/usr/bin/wc` or `/bin/wc`, depending on the OS.

In order to make your new command behave like the existing ones on the system, the program implementing it has to be installed somewhere in [the `PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). It is common on Linux distributions to put `$HOME/bin` into the user's `PATH` if the directory is present on login. If you want the command to be available to all users on the system, you probably want to put it somewhere else, like `/usr/local/bin`.